# How can I make a control in Wpf depend on a property in viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have this codes, but I don't want just make control visible or invisible , I don't want to create it, because it works in background and does some work that takes time and I don't want it. how can I do that? Can I use if condition in `xaml` in `wpf`? I've heard about triggers but I don't know how to do that in my example?

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewService[NoteSaveView]}" Visibility="{Binding ViewModeVisibility[Insert]}"/>
    
<telerik:RadTabControl TabOrientation="Horizontal" TabStripPlacement="Right" Padding="5" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 -5 -5 -5" Visibility="{Binding ViewMode,Converter={StaticResource UpdateViewToVisibility}}">
<telerik:RadTabItem Header="صفحه اصلی" Content="{Binding ViewService[NoteSaveView]}"/>
<telerik:RadTabItem Header="تاریخچه" Content="{Binding ViewService[LogView]}"/>
</telerik:RadTabControl>
```

Edit:
finally I solved my problem with this code:

```
<ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ViewModeVisibilityToContent}">
                    <Binding Path="ViewModeVisibility[Insert]"/>
                    <Binding Path="ViewService[NoteSaveView]"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ContentControl.Content>
        </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Have you looked at [ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector?view=net-5.0) ?

Comment: If you found the answer to your question, you should add a proper answer (don't just post the code you came up with but also explain how it solves your problem) and accept that answer instead of adding the solution inside of your question through an edit

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `DataType` property of a `DataTemplate` and then assign a data object to the property to activate a `DataTemplate` or `null` to deactivate it.
In the code below you just need to set `PropertyInViewModel` of type `object` in viewmodel to some `int` to activate the `DataTemplate`, or to `null` to deactivate it.

```
<StackPanel xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:Int32}">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Beige" Background="Brown" Height="20" Width="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding PropertyInViewModel}"/>
</StackPanel>
```